# How to Synch Core Data Between multiple ViewControllers in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm trying to synch the core data between more than one ViewController. I have an attribute called Score, which is in my Core Data model. In the first ViewController:

```
// Defining context
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
```

The following code is inside this first ViewController:

```
// Creating a new username & Saving it to Core Data
    let newUser = UserInfo(context: self.context)
    newUser.name = usersName.text
    newUser.birthday = bdPicker.date
    newUser.gender = genderTextField.text!
    newUser.prevTested = yesOrNoTextField.text!
    newUser.score = 0


    // Core Data calling method
    saveInfo()

func saveInfo(){
    do {
        try self.context.save()
    } catch {
        print("Error saving context\(error)")
    }
}
```

In the remaining ViewControllers, I want to access the Score attribute and modify it. Now, how is it possible to access all Score attribute from all the remaining controllers in my app.

Comment: First, Core Data code probably doesn't belong in a view controller. It should be in a model class, but ignoring that, `newUser` is just an object.  Pass that object reference to other view controllers and they can read/write the `score` attribute.

Comment: @Paulw11 The `newUser` is inside `@IBAction fun buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton)`. So, once it's clicked I'll create the object. In the other controllers, how is it possible to pass the reference of `newUser`?

Comment: You need to use a property instead of a local variable